# Cancel full screen mode in Firefox without F11

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

How do I cancel the full screen mode in Firefox (currently V70) without using the F11 key on the keyboard?

I know I can do it through a virtual keyboard (see my own answer) but I'm looking for an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the mouse to the top right (or left) corner of the screen; click on the hamburger "menu" button (displayed as ≡) and select the double arrow (something like ⤢) at the right of the line starting with **Zoom** to toggle "full screen" mode.

Comment: I didn't have any "menu button" but moving the mouse to the top edge gave me the regular windows buttons (minimize, maximize and close), which worked fine as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a possible workaround in some cases: use a virtual keyboard. But this is tedious to get to (lots of clicks) if you haven't set it up before hand (e.g. on a new system).